# Specific solution for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can somebody explain step-by-step, as I can't understand, how to find the particular solution of the ODE?

1) $y' + y = 1$

2) $y' + 2y = 2 + 3x$

Comment: What method(s) do you know to find such a particular solution?

Comment: To use dy/dx + P(x)y = Q(x), so according to the 1st equation, P(x) = 1 and Q(x) = 1, but I don't know what to do next

Comment: I have found a homogenous solution for the 1st equation, y = Ce^(-x)

Comment: Yes, these are (of the form of) first order lineair DE's; but there are different methods and I'm guessing you are supposed to use a particular one. What method(s) have you seen to solve DE's of this type?

Comment: Method of undetermined coefficients, Separable differential equation ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, here are some steps.

1) You already found the homogeneous solution $y_h = Ce^{-x}$. Since the RHS is a constant, you propose a particular solution of the form $y_p = A$ where $A$ is a constant you still have to determine. Substitution in the differential equation yields:
$$A'+A=1 \Leftrightarrow 0+A=1$$
so $y_p = 1$, making the complete solution $y=Ce^{-x}+1$. This differential equation was also separable, so you could check this result with another method.

2) I assume you'll be able to find the homogeneous solution for this one as well? Now the RHS is a first order polynomial, so you propose a particular solution of the form $y_p = Ax+B$. Again, you have to determine the constants $A$ en $B$; substitute into the differential equation. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Both equations are first-order linear differential equations.

A quick trick (but one that shouldn't be appreciated) is to use integrating factors to solve these problems:

Consider a differential equation of the form:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} + P(x)y = Q(x) $$

We multiply both sides of the equation with an integrating factor 
$$ I = e^{\int P(x)\text{d}x}$$

$$ I\frac{dy}{dx} + IP(x)y = IQ(x) $$

Now, integrating both sides:

$$ \int I\frac{dy}{dx} + IP(x)y \hspace{3pt}\text{d}x = \int IQ(x) \hspace{3pt}\text{d}x $$

The LHS is:

$$ \int \left(e^{\int P(x)\text{d}x}\frac{dy}{dx} + e^{\int P(x)\text{d}x}P(x)y \hspace{3pt}\right)\text{d}x = ye^{\int P(x)\text{d}x}=Iy $$

So, all you have to do is solve the RHS:

$$ Iy = \int IQ(x) \hspace{3pt}\text{d}x = \int e^{\int P(x)\text{d}x}Q(x) \hspace{3pt}\text{d}x $$

Applying this method to Problem $1)$:

$$ I = e^{\int \text{d}x} = e^x $$

Therefore,

$$ ye^x = \int e^x \text{d}x = e^x + c $$

Rearranging the terms, we get:

$$ y = 1+ce^{-x} $$

Apply the same method to Problem $2)$!